# In PyCharm docker Interpreter tab is missing

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, interpreter

I've installed *PyCharm Community edition **2020.1*** in the windows machine & I've installed docker version i.e. 2.1.0.4 and use expose daemon which is shown in the image below:

[image: docker]

I've set up a Django project in the docker container everything is working fine. Now I want to configure docker container inside the PyCharm so I've installed a plugin in PyCharm i.e. **Docker**, that plugin image attached here:

[image: Docker Plugin]

I've configured it & it's also working fine, but when I set the Project Interpreter, the *docker tab is **missing**.*

[image: Python Interpreter is missing]

Now I want to configure docker's python environment in the PyCharm Interpreter, Please give your advice, what's wrong in the configuration or If I missed some steps please let me know so that I can configure it properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html - Docker integration is a pro feature.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is docker plugin provide any help into it?

Comment: But it can be added via a plugin. As per this link above. I cannot see it either though.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm Community Edition does not support this. If you want to have a Docker interpreter in PyCharm you must have PyCharm Professional.

Still actual in 2024
[source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403483524242-Can-t-see-the-Docker-option-under-python-Interpreter-to-connect-remotely)